# Clean method of sharing an object (or state) between modules with AMD and Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, amd, thorax.js

I've got a Backbone/AMD app and what I would like to do is have a model/object be fetched in the main module when the app loads, then be either accessible to or be able to be loaded into subsequent modules without the overhead of re-fetching it (it's a permissions model and thus is required pretty much everywhere).

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make it its own dependency:

```
define(["backbone", "text!api/v1/user/permissions"],
       function(Backbone, permissionJSON) {
         return new Backbone.Model(JSON.parse(permissionJSON));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great! and +1 for the `text!` trick, I never even realised it was making a proper http req and can be used like that. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you require a module for which you want to keep state you can do as follows

**stateMod.js**

```
require(['jquery', 'lib1','lib2'], function($, l1,l2) {


  var thisVariableHoldsStateBetweenModules = "initValue"

  var thisIsTheAPIOfYourModule = function(newValue) {

    thisVariableHoldsStateBetweenModules = newValue

  }

  var getInternalState = function () {

    return thisVariableHoldsStateBetweenModules 

  }

  return {

     set: thisIsTheAPIOfYourModule,
     get: getInternalState 
  }

}
})
```

What you get back when you require this module is `thisIsAPIOfYourModule`, so you can just use it to change `thisVariableHoldsStateBetweenModules`:

**otherMod.js**

```
require(['stateMod'], function(stateMod) {

  stateMod.set("Hello world")

})
```

and later on, in module **nextMod.js**:

```
require(['stateMod'], function(stateMod) {

   stateMod.get() // outputs Hello World

})
```

[requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) saves the object returned from the first time it is required, and this why you don't re-load (network wiise) d3js and jQuery or other common libs every time you need them in a module, otherwise it would be pretty crap.

Give this a go and let me know how it worked for you.